# Excel formula relating to the date in previous cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

I have started a new job and inherited a complex and badly organised Excel workbook that is used to document dates of dealing with particular clients.

I need to find a way to highlight a cell if the date in the previous cell is over a week ago and the cell I am formatting is blank. I have used conditional formatting in the past, but can only seem to do it relating to that cell itself, not the one in the previous column.

I have Excel 2016.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume:

- The "previous" dates you're checking for being >7 days old are in column A
- The cells you want to highlight are in column B

Then:

1. Select `B1`
2. Create a new Conditional Formatting rule of the type **Use a formula to determine which cells to format**
3. In the formula box enter `=A1<TODAY()-7`

   **Note:**  Based on the updated question requiring that the format only apply if the cell to be highlight is blank, the formula is:

   ```
   =AND(A1<TODAY()-7,B1="")
   ```
4. Configure to rule to format cell `B1` as desired
5. Use the Format Painter to copy the conditional format to the other cells in column B as desired

---

#### How This Works

Conditional formats are always applied to the cell that should be formatted differently.  However, the condition(s) that determine when the format should be applied can look at other cells.

In this example, the formula used to determine when the conditional format is applied looks at the cell *one cell left* of the cell being formatted because  the formula uses a relative reference to refer to cell `A1`. It matters which cell you select when creating the conditional format (B2 in this case) because the relative location between said cell and the one referred to by the formula is preserved for all other cells to which the format is applied.

For example, when the conditional format is applied to cell B2, Excel will update the formula to be:

```
=A2<TODAY()-7
```

Or if the conditional format is applied to cell D5 the formula will become

```
=C5<TODAY()-7
```

In each case, the formula will refer to one cell to the left.

If you wanted to refer to two cells to the right and two cells down, then when creating the format in cell B2 you would enter the following formula:

```
=D3<TODAY()-7
```

...because `D3` is two cells to the right and two rows down from cell `B2`.

---

#### Further Reading

You can do lots of useful things with absolute, relative (discussed here), or mixed references in Excel.  See [Switch between relative, absolute, and mixed references](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Switch-between-relative-absolute-and-mixed-references-dfec08cd-ae65-4f56-839e-5f0d8d0baca9)

Comment: Thank you. There is a tick button for Stop if True, should that be ticked?

How do I find the formula painter tool?

Comment: Stop if True is only meaningful if a single cell has multiple conditional formats *and* you want a certain format to take precedence in the case multiple apply. The format painter is accessed by right-clicking the "source" cell having the format to copy, then clicking the icon that looks like a paintbrush.

Comment: can i add to the formula to stop if the cell is not black? so cell is highlighted if date is over a week and the cell itself is blank?

Comment: =AND(I54<TODAY()-7,J54="")

Comment: This is formula and cell is lighting when it is blank but date is not over 7 days?

Comment: Is 1) The date in `I54` greater than 7 days ago, AND 2) Cell `J54` empty?

Comment: The date is yesterday and the cell is empty.

Comment: Your question asks about highlighting cells *"if the date in the previous cell is over a week ago"*. Did you perhaps mean "If the date is *less* than a week old"?

Comment: ...If so, use this formula: `=AND(A1>TODAY()-7,B1="")`

Answer (score 1):

I used the conditional formatting formula: =$A2<(TODAY()-7)
in the range: =$B$2:$B$19

See below.

[image: Formatting Rules]

[image: Formatting Rules]

[image: Excel screenshot]